# How to implement httponly cookie in Next 13?

Tags: authentication, cookies, token, next.js13, httponly

I'm developing an application using Next.js 13 with PHP as the backend for serving APIs. I've implemented a login form and successfully handled the POST request for login. After a successful login, the backend sets an HTTP-only token as a cookie in the user's browser. Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to handle this HTTP-only token in my Next.js 13 application. Despite researching various articles and watching numerous YouTube videos, I haven't found a solution that addresses my specific needs. I'd appreciate any assistance or insights on this matter.

here are few articles i read but did not find solution that helped

[article-1](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/next-js-secure-authentication-using-http-only-cookie-graphql-or-rest-a4ef94cec9e8)
[article-2](https://maxschmitt.me/posts/next-js-http-only-cookie-auth-tokens)